# VMWare gets stuck after trying to copy a large file

Tags: windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm using WMWare Workstation in a Windows 10 host, with a Windows 10 guest machine. I tried copying a large file (50 Mb.) from host to guest. The copy got stuck after a few minutes, and VMWare became unresponsive: whenever I tried stopping it I got the message "The guest VM is busy", or something like that. In the end I had to use Task Manager on the host to kill it.

So, I deleted the stuck VM with all the temp files and restored it from a backup, with all the .vmdk, .vmx, .vmxf, .nvram, .vmsd... files. But when I tried to start the fresh VM, it got stuck again: the VM didn't even boot, it just showed a black screen and became just as unresponsive as before.

So, what can I do to recover this VM? (And by "recover" I mean being able to boot it normally again). I thought I had "cleaned" everything up by deleting the VM's files, but perhaps I missed something?

Comment: Not a fix but a way to avoid the problem: After the copy operation got stuck, not killing/stopping any VMWare processes and rebooting the host system (shutting down all running processes in the dialog that appears after clicking reboot) avoids getting stuck in the black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1) VM will not start.**

Those files above are the correct files for a Windows guest.

Make sure your backup is secure.

Copy the folder to a new location within your Virtual Machine folder.

In VMware Workstation make a new VM and point it to settings file in this new folder. See if you can see the settings and make sure all the settings are correct.

See if you can open the guest machine.  Let us assume so.

If, however, the temp files you deleted included non-committed snapshots, then you may not be able to re-create the machine. In this case, you would need to build a new machine.

**(2) Copy a large file:**

Make sure you are using VMware Workstation V15.5.6 (newest) and update if you need to.

Map the folder of the host machine in the guest using the NET USE and IP address.

In the guest machine, make sure you see the host folder as a drive letter. This is a mapped connection, not a browsed connection.

See if you can copy the file. I just copied a 600 MB file from host to guest with VMware Workstation V15.5.6 with no difficulty. No stalling.

Comment: Well, it worked! In the end I had to not only copy the VM files from backup, but also rename its folder; otherwise VMWare seemed to keep identifying it as the "old" one.